# IIS Hostable Web Core host ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, host

How can i **self host** my asp.net mvc website inside c# console application or windows service using **IIS Hostable Web Core**
I tried to using this sample: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/04/14/hostyourownwebserverusingiis7.aspx
but it didn't work for net 4.5.

Can someone suggest me a way to do it please.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of research i decided to use a different approach: use iis express to host my website locally using C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe and then setting systray to false it can be completely invisible to enduser, so i created a windows service that on start creates iisexpress process and host my website with my configurations and on stop kills this process,i know that the perfomance of iisexpress is less but it's was fine for me and easy to deploy.